# Gluing sheaves - can we realize $\mathcal{F}(W)$ as some kind of limit?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{U_i\}$ and open cover for $X$. Suppose we have sheaves $\mathcal{F}_i$ on $U_i$ and for each $i,j$ an isomorphism $\varphi_{ij} : \mathcal{F}_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathcal{F}_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ such that $\varphi_{ii} = id$ and $\varphi_{ik} = \varphi_{jk} \circ \varphi_{ij}$ on $U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k$. I want to define some kind of sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$; to do this we consider

$$\mathcal{F}(W) := \Big\{(s_i)_{i \in I}, s_i \in \mathcal{F}_i(W \cap U_i) : \varphi_{ij}(s_i|_{W \cap U_i \cap U_j}) = s_j|_{W \cap U_i \cap U_j}  \Big\}.$$

> > **My question is:** Can we realise $\mathcal{F}(W)$ as some kind of limit of a diagram, or yet as an equalizer  of two maps? I ask this because I want to show that this $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf. At the moment it seems to me that $\mathcal{F}(W)$ is very close to being some kind of ``inverse limit", but I don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: You are exactly right, the restriction maps give you an inverse system, and so the "glued" sheaf is just the inverse limit of this system.

Comment: @RobertAuffarth Not exactly. The problem is that if we want the abelian groups in question to be $\mathcal{F}_i(W\cap U_i) =: A_i$ then what is the morphism from $A_j$ to $A_i$ say? It cannot be $\varphi_{ij}$...

Comment: You're right, sorry about that!

Comment: $\phi_{ii}=1$ is superfluous, it follows from the rest.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer your question, the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ you are trying to construct can be described in the category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ as the limit of a certain diagram. We will consider sheaves on an open subset $U \subseteq X$ as sheaves on $X$ by the usual direct image construction.

- The diagram has one vertex for every ordered pair of elements in the open cover; the object at the vertex $(i, j)$ is the sheaf $\mathscr{F}_i |_{U_i \cap U_j}$.
- We have an edge $(i, i) \to (i, j)$ for every ordered pair $(i, j)$; the corresponding morphism $\mathscr{F}_i \to \mathscr{F}_i |_{U_i \cap U_j}$ is the restriction map.
- We have an edge $(i, j) \to (j, i)$ for every ordered pair $(j, i)$; the corresponding morphism $\mathscr{F}_i |_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathscr{F}_j |_{U_j \cap U_i}$ is the isomorphism $\varphi_{i,j}$.

The cocycle condition guarantees that all the triangles appearing in the diagram commute. Thus we have a well-defined diagram in $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ and we can take its limit.

Amusingly, there is another sense in which gluing sheaves is a limit construction: the category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ itself is a bicategorical limit of a (pseudo)commutative diagram involving all the categories $\mathbf{Sh}(U_i)$, $\mathbf{Sh}(U_i \cap U_j)$, and $\mathbf{Sh}(U_i \cap U_j \cap U_k)$. In fancy language, we say that $\mathbf{Sh}(-)$ is a **stack** for the canonical topology on the site of open subsets of $X$.

Comment: Dear Zhen, thanks for your answer. 1) Is it true that arbitrary limits exist in $\textbf{Sh}(X)$? Also, is it true that the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ I produced above is the limit of your diagram in your answer?

Comment: Yes on both counts.

Comment: Zhen Lin, Can this bicategorical limit be expressed as a strict 1-limit of categories? For the stack of sheaves on a topological space, do we really need higher limits, or is 1-category theory enough?

Comment: Yes, but that involves many technical details. (In the first place, what we have is not a commutative diagram but rather a pseudocommutative diagram.)

Comment: Good to know, because I am in the process of checking it for myself. Thanks.

Comment: Let me be clear: you can compute it as a limit for a strictly commutative diagram of the same shape, but the vertices and arrows are _different_.

Comment: @ZhenLin I asked about this realization of a 1-limit [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794340/expressing-the-stack-of-sheaves-with-1-limits), if you have the time and energy to explain :)

Comment: @ZhenLin Excuse me please that I have to ask, but I have some difficulties in understanding "The cocycle condition guarantees that all triangles appearing in the diagram commute". I don't see at the moment how we can compose the transition maps of the second type, since a $\varphi_{ij}$ ends at a $i_*(\mathcal{F}_{j|U_i\cap U_j})$, and a $\varphi_{jk}$ starts at a $i_*(\mathcal{F}_{j|U_j\cap U_k})$. I would be glad for some sort of help/clarification.