# Cocycle condition in gluing sheaves of modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am reading Hartshorne. I can basically understand gluing sheaves like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852777/cocycle-condition-in-gluing-sheaves). But, I still get confused about gluing *sheaves of modules* on schemes.

Suppose I have a scheme $X$ obtained by gluing $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$ for a family of commutative rings $A_i$. Specifically, by Exercise 2.12 in Hartshorne, we may assume there are ring isomorphisms
$$
g_{ij}: A_j\to A_i
$$
such that $g_{ik}=g_{ij}\circ g_{jk}$, and use this data to interpret $X$. (More precisely, we should think $\mathrm{Spec}(A_ij) \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$, but let's abuse the notations. Hope this does not cause serious issues).

According to Proposition 5.1 in Hartshorne, a local sheaf $\mathscr F_i$ of modules on $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$ is equivalent to an $A_i$-module $M_i$ by setting $\mathscr F_i=\tilde M_i$.

Now, we aim to glue these local sheaves. Let's get back to Exercise 1.22 for gluing sheaves. What is the condition for gluing these sheaves $\mathscr F_i=\tilde M_i$ on $\mathrm{Spec}(A_i)$?

By Proposition 5.2, I was wondering if we should consider homomorphisms of modules
$$
G_{ij}: M_i\to A_i\otimes_{A_j}M_j \quad \text{or}\quad  A_j\otimes_{A_i} M_i\to M_j
$$
where for the tensor product, we need to view $A_j$ as an $A_i$-module via $g_{ij}:A_i\to A_j$.
However, if so, the cocycle condition in Exercise 1.22 makes me confused; we cannot simply set $G_{ij}\circ G_{jk}=G_{ik}$ since $M_i$ are modules over different $A_i$'s.

> **Question:** Is there a **purely algebraic** way to understand the cocycle condition for gluing sheaves of modules? Here "purely algebraic" means that we only use rings, modules, morphisms among them, etc.

Comment: Your description of the gluing of $X$ from its affine charts is not right. The isomorphisms should only be on the overlaps. Note also that unless $X$ is separated we cannot expect intersections of affine open subschemes to be affine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should be maps of modules over the same sheaf of rings. There is nothing special about the case of schemes here so let's work in the general case that $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a ringed space.

Let $\{U_i\}$ be an open cover of $X$ and $\mathscr{F}_i$ a collection of $\mathcal{O}_{U_i}$-modules. To glue these we need to give isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_{U_i \cap U_j}$ modules $\psi_{ij}: \mathscr{F}_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} \to \mathscr{F}_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$ which needs to satisfy the cocycle condition. Let $i, j, k$ be indices and denote $U_{ijk} = U_i \cap U_j \cap U_j$. Then this condition requires that the composition $$\mathscr{F}_i|_{U_{ijk}} \stackrel{\psi_{ij}|_{U_{ijk}}}\longrightarrow \mathscr{F}_j|_{U_{ijk}} \stackrel{\psi_{jk}|_{U_{ijk}}}\longrightarrow \mathscr{F}_k|_{U_{ijk}} $$ agrees with $\psi_{ik}|_{U_{ijk}}$. We see here that these are all modules over the same sheaf of rings (namely, $\mathcal{O}_{U_{ijk}}$), so nothing funny is happening.

EDIT: Let's look at the situation that $U_i = U_{ii} = \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ are affine schemes, $U_{ij} \subset \operatorname{Spec} A_i$ are open subschemes together with isomorphisms $g_{ij}: U_{ij} \to U_{ji}$ which satisfy the requirements of exercise II.2.12 to glue these $U_i$ to a scheme $X$, together with open embeddings $j_i: U_i \hookrightarrow X$.

Now, suppose are given $\mathscr{F}_i$ on each $U_i$. We may identify $U_i$ with $j_i(U_i)$ and similarly $\mathscr{F}_i$ with ${j_i}_* \mathscr{F}_i$. Under these identifications, the gluing data for a quasicohernet sheaf of modules is the same as above; we should give sheaves of modules on each $U_i$ with isomorphisms on the overlaps satisfying the cocylce condition.

We can untangle some of these indentifications to perhaps see what's going on better. Without these identifications, $\mathscr{F}_i|_{U_{ij}}$ and $\mathscr{F}_j|_{U_{ji}}$ are not sheaves on the samed ringed space so as you said, we would need to specify isomorphisms of $\mathcal{O}_{U_{ji}}$-modules $\psi_{ji}: {g_{ij}}_*(\mathscr{F}_i|_{U_{ij}}) \to \mathscr{F}_j|_{U_{ji}}$ satisfying the cocycle condition.

This is a bit strange because we would also want $\psi_{ij}$ to be the inverse of $\psi_{ji}$ somehow. We can can do this by defining/insisting that $\psi_{ij} = {g_{ji}}_*(\psi_{ji}^{-1})$.

As for the cocycle condition, we can insist that for $i, j, k$, on $U_{ki} \cap U_{kj} \subset \operatorname{Spec} A_k$ the composition $${g_{ik}}_*(\mathscr{F}_i|_{U_{ij} \cap U_{ik}}) \stackrel{{g_{jk}}_*\psi_{ji}}\longrightarrow {g_{jk}}_*(\mathscr{F}_j|_{U_{ji} \cap U_{jk}}) \stackrel{\psi_{kj}}\longrightarrow \mathscr{F}_k|_{U_{ki} \cap U_{kj}}$$ agrees with $\psi_{ki}|_{U_{ki} \cap U_{kj}}$ as maps of $\mathcal{O}_{U_{ki} \cap U_{kj}}$ modules. Note that if you push forward by $j_k$ you obtain the same cocycle condition described above. (also, to suppress notation I ommitted some of the restrictions on the maps in the above sequence)

Comment: Thanks. I still get confused. Suppose $\psi=\psi_{ij}$ covers the transition map $\varphi=\varphi_{ij}:U_{ij} \to U_{ji}$. Then, should I consider morphisms $\psi_{ij}: \mathcal F_i \to \varphi_* \mathcal F_j$, where the target sheaf is the direct image by the transition map.

Comment: @Pixie Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure I understand; wouldn't $\varphi$ be the identity map in the case you described? (I'm not sure what other natural ringed space maps there are $U_i \cap U_j \to U_j \cap U_i = U_i \cap U_j$.) In this case, $\varphi_*$ would just be the identity functor.

Comment: If we regard $\mathbb {CP}^1$ as the gluing of two copies of $\mathbb C$, then the transition map looks like $\varphi: z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$. If we consider the subsets $U_0$ and $U_1$ inside $\mathbb {CP}^1$, then we might say it is the identity. But, we should specify some isomorphisms $U_i\cong\mathbb C$, so I think it may be not just the identity.

Comment: Oh! I did misunderstand then. This is somewhat different (a special case maybe) of what I described. I'll add an edit. Since the data gluing the open schemes together satisfies the cocycle condition already the situation is considerably simpler.